# Update Global Variables Input as Parameters Rather Than Returning Results From Function

Tags: python, function

## Goal

I am trying to write a function where one or more of the input parameters is a global variable that is updated by the function, without having to `return` values from within the function. I am aware I could just return a tuple or two separate values from the function, but I think updating the global variables from within the function would be another interesting method if it is possible.

### Reason to do this

Updating global variables with a function is easy when the global variable is known (ie. defined previously in the python script). However, I want to define the function in a separate .py file to easily use the function within other python scripts. Therefore, I need to be able to support different variable names to update.

While this is not at all necessary, I am just interested if this is even possible.

#### Example Pseudocode

I'm thinking something like this:

```
def math_function(input_val, squared_result, cubed_result):
    squared_result = input_val**2 #update the var input as the squared_result parameter
    cubed_result = input_val**3 #update the var input as the cubed_result parameter
```

where you would input a number for `input_val` and then global variables for `squared_result` and `cubed_result` that the function updates with the result. It would then theoretically work like:

```
#Declare global variables
b = 0
c = 0

#then somewhere in the code, call the function
math_function(2, b, c)

#check the new values
print(b) #Output: b = 4
print(c) #Output: c = 8
```

This would allow me to use the function in different python scripts without having to worry about what order the results are returned in.

Comment: Python passes parameters by value, not by reference. So assigning to a parameter variable has no effect on the caller's variable.

Comment: The fundamental problem with this is that you can't pass variables around in Python. You can only pass objects. Your function receives arguments `2`, `0`, and `0`, not `2`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: The only way you can do this is by passing a mutable container object. Then the function can modify its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I am in no way *advocating* this.

You could use the `globals` builtin function to access a global variable by name:

```
def gtest(name,value):
    globals()[name] = value

gtest('new_global','new_value')
print(new_global)
```

Comment: This accesses the wrong module's globals if you call it from a different module.

Comment: This achieved what I was looking for when the function is defined within the same script as the variables I am accessing. It is interesting to know how to do, but like you said is probably not advisable. I have not yet tried within a different module, I suspect it may not work across imported modules since the `globals()` function accesses the dictionary of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not advocating this too, I would like to hear everyone's thoughts, but this can be done -

```
my_global = [0, 0]


def my_math_func(x, g):
   g[0] = x ** 2
   g[1] = x ** 3

my_math_func(3, my_global)
```